# Preserve Spaces in locating relative file path of shell script

Tags: shell, path

I am trying to execute a file using a shell script on a remote server.  I am having mild success with the following code:

```
#!/bin/bash
pushd $(dirname "${0}") > /dev/null
basedir=$(pwd -L)
popd > /dev/null
echo "${basedir}"
```

But part of the relative path has a folder name with  a space in it.  How do I preserve this space with character escaping?

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your relative path variable in double quotes. This should interpret a path with spaces.

Example:
Consider a directory on the Desktop with the name `untitled folder`. In a shell, this could be executed correctly:

```
$> myDirectory="~/Desktop/untitled folder"
$> ls -al "$myDirectory"
```